# Некорректная форма отчета при выгрузке с JasperServer

Tags: jasperreports, jasperstudio

Для генерации отчета использую CROSSTAB. Отчет выгружается в xlsx.
[image: Пример формы] Как видно на изображении, заголовок отчета состоит из нескольких столбцов, причем последний столбец разбит на 3 строки.
При выгрузке отчета в формате xlsx через JasperServer изменяется его структура, а именно верхняя строка с заголовками разбивается на 3 строки (как в последнем столбце). Причем, при выгрузке xlsx в JasperStudio файл корректен, при выгрузке в docx через JasperServer файл также корректен. То есть проблема только  с xlsx через JasperServer!
[image: Корректный формат Jasper Studio]
[image: Некорретный формат Jasper Server]
Если кто-то сталкивался с такой проблемой подскажите решение